# Mysql Cluster not working on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

I am unable to setup MySQL Cluster on ubuntu servers. As a starting point I started from the  [link](http://stepbysteparticles.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48&Itemid=54) but I am not successful and the tar ball  version I download is 6.3.45. As I wanted to test the mysql cluster, the Data node and SQL node are same but sql never appeared as connected(mysqld on sql node is running`/etc/init.d/mysql.server start`) in management node console and it looks like below.

```
[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s)
id=2 @192.168.1.107 (Version: version number, Nodegroup: 0, Master)
id=3 @192.168.1.108 (Version: version number, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1 @192.168.1.105 (Version: version number)

[mysqld(API)] 2 node(s)
id=4 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.1.107)
id=5 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.1.108)
```

On all the 3 machines mysql-server & client(`apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`) were already installed and I completely stopped and also removed them at the system start up.

Now the mysqld is from extracted cluster tar ball(`/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server`). As for testing, I created a test database on both the data nodes but the tables are also not syncing on other node. I checked many links, configurations are remained similar in all the links but somewhere it's going wrong. Any more extra package is required?, Could anyone help me here? I am trying this for past 3 days.

**Update 1**:

Is there any bug with Ubuntu and mysql-cluster, I am still not successful with cluster 7. Everywhere it's same configuration and working for everyone and why not for me?. Anymore help? please!

**Update 2**:

Anybody give me working tutorial of `mysql-cluster` on ubuntu(`10.04`), just a successfully working guide...

**EDIT 3**:

Anybody take up and guide me please...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working!. As I said I already had the`mysql-server` and `mysql-client` installed from apt, this was causing the problem and I am not sure how this could be problematic with `mysql-cluster` when I stopped and removed them starting from system startup. Somehow I could see mysql-cluster doing it's job after removing the mysql from apt by,

```
#dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql

#apt-get remove mysql-client mysql-client-5.1 mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1
```

Don't know what the problem between mysql-cluster(build install) and mysql-server(from apt though it's not running).

---

**EDIT**: SORRY!

Don't know what happened suddenly, it's not working since yesterday. Actually I am unable to find out the pkg requirement for mysql-cluster, is `mysql-server` or `mysql-client` should be installed and running along with cluster or a mysql-cluster alone is enough for running SQL(mysqld) and data nodes?. 
Now it's not woking, mysqld(`/etc/init.d/mysql.server`) is not starting and giving the following error:

```
Starting MySQL
 * Couldn't find MySQL manager (/usr/bin/mysqlmanager) or server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe)
```

On another node(having same problem) I even tried copying `/usr/local/bin/*` to `/usr/bin` but still no use and it was showing the below error when I try to start mysqld in this machine:

```
................... * Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

This happened after installing libaprutil1-dev(`apt-get install libaprutil1-dev`) on both the machines. Anybody has any working link of mysql-cluster setup on ubuntu?

---

### Update

I got the issues I had fixed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86120/how-do-i-set-up-a-mysql-cluster/86914#86914) and it's working now!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend either MySQL Cluster 7.1 which is the current GA release or 7.2 which is the Development Milestone Release (planned as next GA). Both can be downloaded here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/

The Getting Started guide will help you get up and running:
http://mysql.com/products/cluster/get-started.html#quickstart

Comment: I gave a try cluster 7, the result is same!!